# Python write random integers to file on newline

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to make a program that generates 10 random integers between 10 and 90 and calls two separate functions to perform separate actions. The first one (`playlist`) simply needs to print them all on one line without spaces, which was easy. The second one (`savelist`) is giving me problems. I need to write every number in the list `nums` to `angles.txt` with each number on a separate line in order. No matter what I try I can't get them on separate lines and it appears as one string on a single line. What am I missing?

```
import random

def main():
    nums = []
    # Creates empty list 'nums'
    for n in range(10):
        number = random.randint(10, 90)
        nums.append(number)
        # Adds 10 random integers to list
    playlist(nums)
    savelist(nums)

def playlist(numb):
    index = 0
    while index < len(numb):
        print(numb[index], end=' ')
        index += 1

def savelist(number):
    myfile = open('angles.txt', 'w')
    # Creates numbers.txt file
    number.sort()
    myfile.write(str(number) + '\n')
    myfile.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In savelist(), you need to loop through the list:

```
myfile = open('angles.txt', 'w')
# Creates numbers.txt file

number.sort()

for e in number:
  myfile.write(str(e))

myfile.close()
```

When you send "nums" to savelist(), you are sending a list.  If you just try to write "numbers" to the file, it's going to write the whole list.  So, by looping through each element in the list, you can write each line to the file.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that. I tried something similar earlier but it seems I was over complicating myself. Thank you!

Comment: I would have earlier, but it said I had to wait for 6 minutes before I could accept an answer. I don't know why that is even a thing on this site, tho I'll admit I didn't expect an answer so soon.

Answer (score 1):

To write a list to a file you need to iterate over each element of the list and write it individually, with the attached newline. For example:

```
def savelist(number):

    myfile = open('angles.txt', 'w')
    # Creates numbers.txt file

    number.sort()

    for n in number:
        myfile.write(str(number) + '\n')

    myfile.close()
```

You could also generate a single string by joining your list with newlines, and then write *that* to the file. For example:

```
    myfile.write('\n'.join([str(n) for n in number])
```

Finally, you may want to consider using a context manager on the file open, to ensure that the file is closed whatever happens. For example:

```
def savelist(nums):

    # Creates numbers.txt file
    nums.sort()

    with open('angles.txt', 'w') as myfile:
        myfile.write('\n'.join([str(n) for n in nums])
```

Note that I also changed the variable name to `nums` rather than `number` ('number' is slightly confusing, since the list contains >1 number!).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out: You are writing an array as a whole to the file, and therefore are seeing only one line.

```
def main():
nums = [] # Creates empty list 'nums'

for n in range(10):
    number = random.randint(10, 90)
    nums.append(number)
    # Adds 10 random integers to list

playlist(nums)

savelist(nums)


def playlist(numb):
    index = 0

    while index < len(numb):
        print(numb[index], end=' ')
        index += 1

def savelist(number):
    myfile = open('angles.txt', 'w')
    # Creates numbers.txt file

    number.sort()
    for element in number:
       myfile.write(str(element) + '\n')

    myfile.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

@tomlester already stated that you need to loop through the elements in `number`. Another way to do this is.

```
def savelist(number):

    number.sort()
    with open('angles.txt', 'w') as myfile:
        myfile.write('\n'.join(map(str, number)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
from random import randint

def rand_lst(lo, hi, how_many):
    return [randint(lo, hi) for _ in range(how_many)]

def print_lst(nums):
    print(''.join(str(num) for num in nums))

def save_lst(nums, fname):
    with open(fname, "w") as outf:
        outf.write('\n'.join(str(num) for num in sorted(nums)))

def main():
    nums = rand_lst(10, 90, 10)
    print_lst(nums)
    save_lst(nums, "angles.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```